# A way of splitting Euler products

Tags: euler-product

I bumped into a claim I am not understanding completely about Euler products. Is it true that
\begin{align}
&\prod_p (1 + a(p) p^{-s} + a(p^2) p^{-2s} + \cdots) \\
&\hspace{2cm}= \prod_p (1 + b(p) p^{-s} + b(p^2) p^{-2s} + \cdots)\\
&\hspace{2cm}\qquad \times \prod_p (1 + (a(p^2)-b(p^2)) p^{-2s} + (a(p^3)-b(p^3)) p^{-3s} + \cdots)?
\end{align}

And also, a second question that may indicate I am missing something: if $f(p) = a(p) + b(p)$ (just for $p$, not for all $p^m$, and even with this I do not see why it should be true), do we have
\begin{align}
&\prod_p (1 + f(p) p^{-s} + f(p^2) p^{-2s} + \cdots) \\
&\hspace{1cm}= \prod_p (1 + a(p) p^{-s} + a(p^2) p^{-2s} + \cdots) \prod_p (1 + b(p) p^{-s} + b(p^2) p^{-2s} + \cdots)?
\end{align}
i.e. the Dirichlet series associated to $f$ factorizing into the product of the Dirichlet series of $a$ and $b$? I thought it was rather the case when $f = a \star b$, the arithmetic convolution of both. Is it better if we assume all these functions to be *completely* multiplicative?

I do not see the magic making it work, so I ask for help.  Even for the $p^2$ term it does not seem to be true?

Comment: Definitely not true, as we can anticipate for general algebraic reasons, and also taking $a(p^n)=1$ and $b(p^n)=p^n$, just restricting attention to the $p$-factor, and (heuristically but also legitimately) viewing $p^{-3s}$ as $0$...

Comment: Do you have a source for this claim? That may help to clarify what's going on.